# Laravel - re-installing app : 'ServiceProvider not found'

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to upgrade my app from 5.1 to 5.2 & ran into some issues. I needed my app back in a working state so i re-uploaded the old version I had backed up on my system. However it is still not working as it was before and Im getting this error :

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146: Class 'Lavary\Menu\ServiceProvider' not found
```

the same error appears when trying to run any composer commands

```
$ composer update
> php artisan clear-compiled



  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Fatal error: Class 'Lavary\Menu\ServiceProvider' not found



Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

& its working without error now.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with Lavary package..Try to configure it again.

Comment: I tried to but i cant even run composer update without an error

Comment: what error you are getting when running composer update?

Comment: I will add the output to the question

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion, try removing Lavary\Menu\ServiceProvider from your config/app.php in providers section and then run composer, install the package Lavary and then add this line back to the app\config.php file